# Comando jquery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Na minha página html, tenho os seguintes elementos:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="visibility:hidden" id="erro">CNS inválido!</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="cns" maxlength="15" required onblur="erro();" />
<script src="paciente.js"></script>
```

Como a página é muito grande, postei apenas os elementos principais e que tem a ver com o problema.

No arquivo paciente.js tenho apenas:

```
function erro(){
  $("#erro").css('visibitily', 'visible');
};
```

O arquivo js é carregado normalmente, porém não apresenta erros e nem funciona.

Comment: A palavra `visibility` está escrita de forma errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A palavra **visibility** está escrita de forma errada, o correto seria:

```
function erro(){
  $("#erro").css('visibility', 'visible');
};
```